# Xamarin designer not loading on mac

Tags: xamarin, designer

I installed Mac OS Sierra on my notebook after completely erasing the hard drive. I continued to install XCode 8.2 and then successfully installed Xamarin. Upon installation I created a single view iOS project. When I tried to open the designer (Main storyboard), it keeps trying to load and eventually after 5 minutes errors out saying unable to load the designer. I downgraded to XCode 7 and was able to open the designer however, then the solution will not compile. Anyone else has had a similar experience?

Comment: Have you tried to open it with xcode?

Comment: The document opens fine with XCode. Here is the error message I received in Xamarin designer after timing out.  "There was a problem rendering this document" I have installed the latest updates for Max OS Sierra as well Xamarin.                                                                 System.Exception: EnsureSession counter too high. Server may be repeatedly crashing. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Session invalid ---> Foundation.ObjCException: NSPortTimeoutException: connection timeout: did not receive reply

Comment: You said you installed XCode 8.2. The latest version is XCode 8.2.1. Please try updating Xcode.

Comment: I actually do have XCode 8.2.1. Sorry I misspoke earlier.

Comment: Searching on that error brought a bug report and a Xamarin forum post. See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19436/mainstoryboard-storyboard-there-was-a-problem-rendering-this-document and https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23215 . If your full exception stack trace is identical to the one in the bug report it would be worth re-opening that bug report adding your information.